# Android intent to navigation app and back

Tags: android, navigation

I'm building an app which is sending an intent with a destination in google's Navigation App.
Here is the coding for the intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
Uri.parse("google.navigation:q=lat,lon");
```

The app works as expected, but now im wondering if there is any way to get back data from the Navigation App to my app when the user reaches the given destination?

Thank you.